# Elasticsearch doesn't work with sonar default instance

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed default SonarQube 4.5 by guideline, and after first ran of sonar on java mavaen project. I have got errors that looks like elasticsearch stopped work. Somebody know this type of cases?

```
2015.02.16 10:33:48 WARN  sea[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1424110483828] [gc][young][973][20] duration [1.6s], collections [1]/[1.8s], total [1.6s]/[24.6s], memory [154.1mb]->[107.1mb]/[990.7mb], all_pools {[young] [68.2mb]->[462.2kb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [8.5mb]->[8.5mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [77.3mb]->[98.1mb]/[691.2mb]}
2015.02.16 10:33:59 WARN  sea[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1424110483828] [gc][young][983][21] duration [1.1s], collections [1]/[1.7s], total [1.1s]/[25.7s], memory [168.7mb]->[117.7mb]/[990.7mb], all_pools {[young] [62mb]->[4.9kb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [8.5mb]->[8.5mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [98.1mb]->[109.2mb]/[691.2mb]}
2015.02.16 10:34:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  18083 requests processed
2015.02.16 10:34:25 INFO  sea[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1424110483828] [gc][young][1008][22] duration [777ms], collections [1]/[1.8s], total [777ms]/[26.5s], memory [184.5mb]->[126.1mb]/[990.7mb], all_pools {[young] [66.8mb]->[1000.5kb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [8.5mb]->[8.2mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [109.2mb]->[116.9mb]/[691.2mb]}
2015.02.16 10:34:34 WARN  sea[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1424110483828] [gc][young][1015][23] duration [1s], collections [1]/[1.9s], total [1s]/[27.6s], memory [185.9mb]->[138.6mb]/[990.7mb], all_pools {[young] [60.7mb]->[1mb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [8.2mb]->[8.5mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [116.9mb]->[129.1mb]/[691.2mb]}
2015.02.16 10:34:46 INFO  web[o.e.client.transport]  [sonar-1424110483828] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][codereview.fastpool.net][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]], disconnecting...org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]][cluster/nodes/info] request_id [515] timed out after [5025ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:356) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
2015.02.16 10:34:56 INFO  web[o.e.client.transport]  [sonar-1424110483828] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][codereview.fastpool.net][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]], disconnecting...org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]][cluster/nodes/info] request_id [516] timed out after [5024ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:356) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
2015.02.16 10:35:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  21516 requests processed
2015.02.16 10:35:06 INFO  web[o.e.client.transport]  [sonar-1424110483828] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][codereview.fastpool.net][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]], disconnecting...org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/127.0.0.1:58512]][cluster/nodes/info] request_id [517] timed out after [5016ms]
```

Comment: It looks like heavy load applied on the server, you can see here that "BulkIndexer" rows are interleaved with timeouts from the cluster. On what kind of machine (CPU, RAM, disk) are you running SonarQube?

Comment: What makes you feel that E/S stopped working? There are only INFO logs.